# Flask, unable to return static file as chosen by user

Tags: python, json, flask

I’m creating a a visualisation of json data which is chosen by the user from a drop down box. The drop down box is populated by the names of json files in folder app/static/Crews.
The javascript d3 code calls a function which uses the chosen json file,

```
d3.json("/data", function(error, graph)
```

This is the code that I use to fill the drop down box,

```
class userInput(Form):
    json_fileCrew = SelectField(u"Filename", choices=[(f, f) for f in filenamesCrew])
```

And this is the function I have to get the json file.

```
def get_data(json_fileCrew):
        json = send_from_directory ("/myproject/app/static/Crews" , json_fileCrew)
        return json
```

I call it in views.py using

```
@app.route("/data", methods=['GET']) 
def data():
        u = userInput()
        json = u.get_data()
        return json
```

And I get this error

```
    json = u.get_data()
  File "\project\myproject\forms.py", line 34,
in get_data
    json = send_from_directory ("/myproject/app/static/Crews" , json_fileCrew)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 612, in send_from_
directory
    filename = safe_join(directory, filename)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 574, in safe_join
    filename = posixpath.normpath(filename)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\posixpath.py", line 335, in normpath
    initial_slashes = path.startswith(sep)
AttributeError: 'userInput' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

I don’t understand why I’m getting this error. I want to look in the folder and return the json file (e.g 1981.json) that has the same name as the one chosen by the user.

**EDIT** Here is the full code for userInput class

```
class userInput(Form):
    json_fileCrew = SelectField(u"Filename", choices=[(f, f) for f in filenamesCrew])

    def get_data(json_fileCrew):
        json = send_from_directory ("/myproject/app/static/Crews",json_fileCrew)
        return json
```

I also tried the below code and it didn't work.

```
 if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(crewPath, json_fileCrew)):
            return send_from_directory(crewPath, json_fileCrew)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get_data` method is... a method.  So the first arg it gets is self, even if you call that arg "json_fileCrew".  It appears you want the method to access the form value for the `SelectField`.  You can access that from a method with `self.json_fileCrew.data`.

```
class UserInput(Form):
    filename = SelectField(choices=[(f, f) for f in crew_files])

    def get_data(self):
        return send_from_directory(crew_path, self.filename.data)
```

---

<sub>The form does not receive json data, and `get_data` does not return json data, so it's not clear why you've named them that way.</sub>

<sub>You are using some unconventional variable names.  See [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for the standard format that most Python programmers expect.</sub>